# android WebView webRTC error CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, chromium

I have a peerJS video call app running on android WebView. I'm getting the following error from logcat

```
 E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(228)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
```

I have granted the permissions using this code:

```
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
                request?.grant(request.resources)
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine and I'm able to stream the video. But, How can I avoid this error? Should I be worried about this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, in my application audio recording didn't work.

Here is my contents for my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
```

I solved this error by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />`

Comment: What’s the difference between RECORD_AUDIO and MICROPHONE?

Comment: @SujithManjavana [MICROPHONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group#MICROPHONE) is to access the microphone audio and [RECORD_AUDIO](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder) is for capturing and encoding audio or video with MediaRecorder, this is is considered a "dangerous" permission

Comment: adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" /> didn’t make any changes in my app.

Comment: I found this code, maybe it can help you
`override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest) {
                if (request.origin.toString() == BASE_URL) {
                    request.grant(request.resources)
                } else {
                    request.deny()
                }`
In my app I get `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(149)] "Could not get input or something went wrong: NotAllowedError: Permission denied", source: https://www....com/.../audioRecord/record.js?version=3.0.3 (149)`  because I didn't have permission.MICROPHONE

Comment: you a life saver